# How to solve error: multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql

I have a query of this type:

```
    Select addMovies.MovieName, GivenBy.UserName, TimeOfReview, Review 
    FROM Users, Reviews, given, addMovies 
    WHERE Reviews.ReviewId = given.ReviewId AND GivenBy.UserName = addMovies.UserName
    ORDER BY TimeOfReview DESC
```

Where schemas of individual tables are of the form

```
   Users (UserName, Password, EmailId, Loc, Info)
   Reviews (ReviewId, ReviewRating, Review)
   Given (ReviewId, UserName)
   addMovies (MovieName, UserName)
```

I am trying to obtain reviews given by a particular user, but its giving me the errors:

**The multi-part identifier "GivenBy.UserName" could not be bound.**

**The multi-part identifier "GivenBy.UserName" could not be bound.**

Could anyone please let me know whats wrong, and what could I do to correct this?

Comment: Shouldn't that be Given.UserName? Of is the table called GivenBy rather than Given?

Comment: The Table (or table reference) 'GivenBy' doesn't appear in the FROM-Part of the Statement.

Comment: Thanks, I have got a given table too, I have got it all jumbled up. Sorry!

Comment: You should use explicit JOIN syntax to avoid accidental cartesian joins such as the missing join you have with Users and Reviews. Also what table is TimeOfReview supposed to be in? It doesn't feature in any of your table schemas.

Comment: It was in the Reviews, think I clipped that part, thanks for the reply, I used INNER JOINS with this query and it works better.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be Given.UserName? Of is the table called GivenBy rather than Given?

Comment: Yep, thanks for the reply, I put that wrong, figured it out now :)

Answer (score 0):

`GivenBy` is not in your `FROM` clause (`given` is) nor is it defined as an alias for a table that *is* in your from clause.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a table called GivenBy to select from. Probably should be:

```
Select addMovies.MovieName, given.UserName, TimeOfReview, Review      
FROM Users, Reviews, given, addMovies      
WHERE Reviews.ReviewId = given.ReviewId AND given.UserName = addMovies.UserName         
ORDER BY TimeOfReview DESC
```